# How to show base activity's view in another activty

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am developing an android application. What I am want to achieve in this app is, I want to make a custom progress bar which has to be available to all the activities. So I created BaseActivity and I added one custom gif in BaseActivity's layout then I created SecondActivity which extends BaseActivity.

BaseActivity(By default gif is invisible) has two methods called showProgressBar and hideProgressBar I am calling this method from SecondActivity but it is not showing a progress bar. Then I make a BaseActivity launcher activity and to check the gif it is showing.

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `setContentView` in your `BaseActivity` and add your base layout there, that way when the child activities call the `setContentView`, the base layout is also set. You'll need to set a `FrameLayout` that will 'hold' the child activity's layout. Something along the following lines should work.

```
//In BaseActivity
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) 
{
    DrawerLayout fullView = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null);
    FrameLayout activityContainer = (FrameLayout) fullView.findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, activityContainer, true);
    super.setContentView(fullView);
}
```

P.S - In my above example, I used a `DrawerLayout`, you should be able to use it with any `ViewGroup`. Just replace that line with the base `ViewGroup` in your base activity layout.

---

**Edit** - Added xml for clarity

```
//activity_base.xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/background_material_dark"
            />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_base"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: what is R.id.activity_content ? is it id from activity_base? if yes, then we can use any id?

Comment: Yes, `activity_content` is the id for the `FrameLayout`. You can use any id you want. (I've added the xml sample in the answer)

Comment: The idea is to set the base activity's layout as the content view, and then inflate the child activity's layout in the `FrameLayout`.

Comment: will try and let you know

Comment: Cool, mark the answer as correct if it works (or comment if you come across any issues), cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom dialog class so it will be available for every Activity in your project

**Create dialogClass:**

```
public class ProgressDialog extends Dialog {

public ProgressDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);

    setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog); //this is your layout for the dialog

    }
}
```

**And all you need to do is to create dialog instant and call it like this:**

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
progressDialog.show(); // this line shows your dialog
```

And in your dialog class, you can put your logic, change the way your layout will look and do anything that you need to.

Comment: thank you for your input. Yes, that's another way of doing it. using this way I need to add ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
progressDialog.show(); this two lines in all the view. If I added this line in base activity then I don't need to copy these lines

Comment: So did it helped you with your problem? you were a bit unclear to me.